# What's the right implementation of google_mobile_ads in flutter with riverpod?

Tags: ios, flutter, google-mobile-ads

### Plugin Version

google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0

### Steps to Reproduce

##### GoogleAdsService.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:textcrawler/providers/admob_providers.dart';

final googleAdServiceProvider =
    Provider<GoogleAdsService>((ref) => GoogleAdsService(ref.read));

class GoogleAdsService {
  final T Function<T>(ProviderListenable<T>) _read;
  GoogleAdsService(this._read);

  final AdRequest request = AdRequest(
    keywords: <String>['foo', 'bar'],
    nonPersonalizedAds: true,
  );

  // maxFailedLoadAttempts
  int _maxFailedLoadAttempts = 3;
  int _numInterstitialLoadAttempts = 0;

  InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;

  final String _bannerAdID = Platform.isAndroid
      ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111'
      : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716';

  // initAds() {
  //   _createInterstitialAd();
  // }

  disposeAds() {
    _interstitialAd?.dispose();
    _read(bannerAdProvider)?.dispose();
  }

  // Interstitial Ad

  void createInterstitialAd() {
    InterstitialAd.load(
      adUnitId: Platform.isAndroid
          ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712'
          : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910',
      request: request,
      adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: (InterstitialAd ad) {
          print('$ad loaded');
          _interstitialAd = ad;
          _numInterstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
          _interstitialAd!.setImmersiveMode(true);
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
          print('InterstitialAd failed to load: $error.');
          _numInterstitialLoadAttempts += 1;
          _interstitialAd = null;
          if (_numInterstitialLoadAttempts < _maxFailedLoadAttempts) {
            createInterstitialAd();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void showInterstitialAd() {
    if (_interstitialAd == null) {
      print('Warning: attempt to show interstitial before loaded.');
      return;
    }
    _interstitialAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) =>
          print('ad onAdShowedFullScreenContent.'),
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad) {
        print('$ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.');
        ad.dispose();
        createInterstitialAd();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (InterstitialAd ad, AdError error) {
        print('$ad onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
        ad.dispose();
        createInterstitialAd();
      },
    );
    _interstitialAd!.show();
    _interstitialAd = null;
  }

  //

  // Banner Ad
  void loadBannerAd() async {
    BannerAd(
      adUnitId: _bannerAdID,
      request: const AdRequest(),
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        // Called when an ad is successfully received.
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          // _bannerAd = ad as BannerAd;
          _read(bannerAdProvider.notifier).update((state) => ad as BannerAd);
        },
        // Called when an ad request failed.
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
          ad.dispose();
        },
        // Called when an ad opens an overlay that covers the screen.
        onAdOpened: (Ad ad) {},
        // Called when an ad removes an overlay that covers the screen.
        onAdClosed: (Ad ad) {},
        // Called when an impression occurs on the ad.
        onAdImpression: (Ad ad) {},
      ),
    ).load();
  }
}
```

##### bannerAdProvider

```
final bannerAdProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose<BannerAd?>((ref) => null);
```

##### UI Implementation

```
    Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0.0,
              child: Consumer(
                builder: (_, ref, __) {
                  BannerAd? bannerAd = ref.watch(bannerAdProvider);
                  if (bannerAd != null)
                    return SizedBox(
                      width: bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
                      height: bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
                      child: AdWidget(ad: bannerAd),
                    );

                  return SizedBox.shrink();
                },
              ),
            )
```

**What's wrong?** After showing ad, it's start printing logs

***After showing BannerAd***

```
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x11f01e1c0 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'XPCConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=4254, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x11f01e220 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Suspended Assertion' for process with PID=4254, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
```

***After 10 to 15 second, keep getting this log***

```
Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x11f01d680 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'XPCConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=4258, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x11f01d920 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Suspended Assertion' for process with PID=4258, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
```

***After closing Interstitial Ad***

```
[ProcessSuspension] 0x11f098120 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'XPCConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=4247, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x11f098180 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Suspended Assertion' for process with PID=4247, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
```

*** Flutter Doctor Log ***

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1, on macOS 13.0 22A8380 darwin-arm64, locale en-PK)
    • Flutter version 3.10.1 on channel stable at /Users/abdullahkhan/Documents/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d3d8effc68 (4 weeks ago), 2023-05-16 17:59:05 -0700
    • Engine revision b4fb11214d
    • Dart version 3.0.1
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/abdullahkhan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E222b
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.66.0
```

**Main Questions**

1. Is this right implementation of google_mobile_ads with riverpod and `bannerAdProvider` should get autoDispose?
2. The logs I'm getting after showing ads are normal or anything wrong with it?